# How to skip filesystem checks during boot

Tags: boot, 20.04, filesystem, lenovo

Whenever I shut down my **Ubuntu 20.04** and reboot, I always get this message at the bottom of my screen:

```
Press Ctrl+C to cancel all filesystem checks in progress
```

This process will take too long and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not have any effect.

How to bypass it?

[image]

Comment: shutdown time is it showing?? 0r a fresh start n reboot time??

Comment: Are you shutting down the machine cleanly?  A `fsck` should only occur after a *configured* number of boots (eg. 30) or a problem was detected last shutdown (eg. power outage or system forced off before shutdown completed)

Comment: @user535733 The file system check is a bug in 20.04, see:   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1875548

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=20.04+filesystem+check

Comment: @karel: It looks to me like the answer you claim is duplicated may have been edited after my answer was posted. This would make your answer the duplicate.

Comment: Since you also posted the same answer at the linked duplicate question I upvoted your answer there, so Ask Ubuntu wouldn't lose good content, even if this question was deleted.

Comment: @karel: I still don't see an answer on that page, (except mine), that answers the question on this page. There is the link to the manpages that mentions fsck.mode, but the manpages do not spell out a solution that a new user can use. The Question is over four years old and refers to 16.04. This bug is specific to 20.04.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Removing Disk Check From 20.04 Boot

The command line option `fsck.mode=skip` can be used to skip the disk check when booting Ubuntu 20.04.

The line `Checking disks: 0% complete` may still come up but fsck will not be run, nor will boot time be increased.

Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the `linux line` in grub.cfg just before `quiet splash`

It is recommended to add the command to grub.cfg by editing /etc/default/grub thus: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="fsck.mode=skip quiet splash"` and then run `sudo update-grub`.

I have had this problem with a Live USB but not with an installed system.

Comment: **Not a good idea. You WANT fsck to run if it finds file system problems**. Better to find/fix the reason for constant file system repairs. Also, fsck will always run when booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Comment: @heynnema: Many people have complained about file system check running after every boot of 20.04 and never actually finding a filesystem error. After a while it gets very old. https://askubuntu.com/search?q=20.04+filesystem+check. This happens every boot in Live systems and every boot in some installed systems. It is not much use if it doesn't help you fix things.

Comment: The automatic filesystem check has been removed from the latest versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: The automatic filesystem check still runs on Ubuntu 22.04, its just that it is running in the background and doesn't slow the boot process. You could confirm this by looking for /run/casper-md5check.json after choosing "Try Ubuntu".

Comment: I am also having this issue on Ubuntu22.04. I have added "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="fsck.mode=skip quiet splash" but it still scans at boot time. Is there any workaround for this?